# elysia_cron setup for custom callback

Tags: 7, cron

I have created a custom callback to perform some batch operation.
How can I set schedule for execution using [elysia_cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron)?

Answer (score 2):

Elysia cron has a hook specifically for that; `hook_cronapi()`:

```
function hook_cronapi($op, $job = NULL) {
  $items['key'] = array(
    'description' => 'string',
    'rule' => 'string',
    'weight' => 1234,
    'callback' => 'function_name', 
    'arguments' => array(...),
    'file' => 'string', // External file, like hook_menu
    'file path' => 'string'
  );

  $items['key2'] = ...
  ...
  return $items;
}
```

Taken from the API.txt file included with the module.

Answer (score 1):

Elysia cron manages all `hook_cron()` implementations, meaning that you need to have `hook_cron()` implementation in your module in order to be able to schedule execution.

Here's an example:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_cron() {
  // Check if the system is already processing your task.
  if (lock_acquire('YOUR_MODULE_cron')) {
    // Do whatever you need here.
    //
    // Release the cron once done, so the process can be triggered again later.
    lock_release('YOUR_MODULE_cron');
  }
}
```

Clear caches, then navigate to `/admin/config/system/cron/settings` and configure how often you want your cron task to run.

See also:

- [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7)
- [`lock_acquire()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!lock.inc/function/lock_acquire/7)
- [`lock_release()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!lock.inc/function/lock_release/7)

Comment: Does this required elysia_cron module?

Comment: No, it does not. You can also run this without Elysia Cron, but you won't be able to schedule execution from admin. You could still do this through code though.

Comment: Using hook_cron with Elysia Cron (and Ultimate Cron) is ok, but it somewhat sidesteps the point of using those modules in the first place. Both modules will manage system cron as a single job, but if you want proper control over the schedule of an individual task you should use the hooks provided by the modules themselves, rather than the system one

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a project where I was trying to add individual cron jobs for feeds importers and run them with elysia cron.

check what I have used to accomplish it.

```
<?php
/**
  * Feed import managed by Elysia
  */

function MY_MODULE_cronapi($op, $job = NULL) {
  $items['feeds_english_cron'] = array(
    'description' => 'Import feeds in english.',
    'rule' => '5 3 * * *', // Everyday at 03:05 AM
    'callback' => 'MY_MODULE_CALLBACK_cron',
    'arguments' => array(array('FEED_NAME')),
  );
  return $items;
}

function MY_MODULE_CALLBACK_cron($feednames) {
  if (function_exists('feeds_source')){
    foreach($feednames as $feedname) {
      $source = feeds_source($feedname);
      $source->import();
    }
  }
}
```